# React Native nest navigators

Tags: react-native

So Currently i'm using `Stack.Navigator` with multiple `Stack.Group` and `Stack.Screens`

now i want to plug on the bottom of the navigator:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
```

But it throws:

[image: Error]

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a component for the screens with bottom navigation, like this:

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabScreens = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen nome={'home'} component={Home} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

And then, put it into Stack Navigator just like a normal component/screen

```js
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name={'TabScreens'} component={TabScreens} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```